# Properties are initiated with an invalid address

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, properties

I have en error that I suspect could be the compiler... I'm not an expert myself, but I checked some other code with the exact same behavior with an expert and we couldn't figure it out.

I setup a property as such:
    @interface aViewController ()

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *listOfTitles;
@end

@implementation aViewController

@synthesize listOfTitles = _listOfTitles;

- (NSArray *)listOfTitles
{
    if (!_listOfTitles)
        _listOfTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"first", @"second", @"third", @"fourth", nil];
    return _listOfTitles;
}
```

However, the app crashes (the array would be more complex and serve to setup textLabel.text properties on UITableViewCell).

What's bothering me, it's that the NSArray always have an invalid address (0x00000001). What am I missing? Isn't this the proper way to do lazy instantiating?

Like I mentionned, I experienced the exact same thing (property instantiated with 0x00000001 ) with other classes, in other projects. That's why I'm suspecting the compiler to be the issue. But really, I'm all ears for solutions!...

Comment: Are you compiling with ARC? If not, you're not managing your memory correctly. If you are, how are you inspecting the values? There's a bug in lldb that affects viewing ivars.

Comment: Do you have an iVar named _listOfTitles declared in your header?

Comment: @lnafziger: The ivar is created by the `@synthesize listOfTitles = _listOfTitles;` directive.

Comment: if you want to define you own getter and setter then better you use dynamic instead of synthesis

Comment: @Sunil: [That's not true](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW9). You can define either or both when using `@synthesize`; `@dynamic` is only for when you _don't_ use `@synthesize` _and_ don't define the accessors in the `@implementation`, but instead provide them elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, I am using ARC, and I am compiling under LLVM 3.1. In case it matters, I am working with Xcode 4.3 and iOS 5.1 SDK...

Comment: @lulius Caesar: I didn't know about the bug about viewing ivars. But at the same time, when going step by step in the debugger, _listOfTitles never gets the values I set to it (based on what I see in the debugger and in the tableView I am creating with it).

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution is to set the ivar to nil in your init function.

```
-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]){
        _listOfTitles = nil;
    }
}
```

The real question is why isn't this being done for you, since all ivars should be initialized to nil. I suspect it has something to do with the property being declared in the .m file. Either way it will cause no harm to nil out the ivar yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't change the behavior. I still get the invalid address. And I can't affect any values to the NSArray...